# Dojo cross domain code not triggering ready() function

Tags: dojo

I am trying to load cross domain dojo components, and although the GET requests that load the javascript files into the browser have a 200 status, the ready() function never fires after the require statement. Note also that in this example the Comp1 component is written in the legacy dojo.provide(), dojo.require(), etc. syntax, and so I have set the async setting to legacyAsyc.

Any suggestions on things I could try to get more information on what is occurring would be great. There are no CORS headers on the GET requests of the js files themselves, but I do not think that this is required for the code to execute (??), as I do not receive any CORS errors in Firebug.

Code/config follows.

Thanks.

```
        dojoConfig = {
        async: "legacyAsync",
        baseUrl: "https://my.remote.domain/path/to/dojo/",
        has: {
            "dojo-debug-messages": true
        },
        tlmSiblingOfDojo: true,
            packages: [{
                name: "myremotestuff",
                location: "../../myremotestuff"
            }],
        trace:{
            "loader-inject":1,
            "loader-define":1,
            "loader-exec-module":1,
            "loader-run-factory":1,
            "loader-finish-exec":1,
            "loader-define-module":1,
            "loader-circular-dependency":1
        },
        isDebug: true,
        cacheBust: true
    };

    ...

<script type="text/javascript">

    console.info("=== SCRIPT BLOCK BEGIN ===");

    require.on('error', function (error) {
        console.info("%%%% require error function fired. error: [ " + error + " ] %%%%");
    });

    require([
        "dojo/ready",
        "myremotestuff/Comp1"
    ], function (ready,comp1) {

        ready(function(){
            console.info("ready() - *Begin* - (I never see these messages, and this line doesn't get hit in debug mode either)");
            console.info("ready() - comp1 defined? " + ( (comp1 !== undefined) && (comp1 !== null) ) );
            console.info("ready() - *End*");
        });

    });

    console.info("=== SCRIPT BLOCK END ===");

</script>
```

Comment: Are ready.js and dojo.js amongst files loaded with status 200?

Answer (score 0):

dojo `require` use under the hood ajax to require your modules.
Whenever ajax is involved in JavaScript Same-origin policy applies.

The [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is a security mechanism of the browser which prevent getting or sending data to a different domain. In your case the `ready` function is not being called because the request of the module is blocked by the browser.

The cleanest and more convenient way to solve this issue is to simply enable CORS on the server where your AMD module resides.

Enabling CORS is pretty easy [here a good tutorial website.](https://enable-cors.org/)

Comment: My organization is running into @user1930364's problem, and your solution doesn't help as the server (which supports CORS, never receives an Origin: header from the browser.

Comment: @ruckc please consider adding a new question on SO including an example of your code, so we can have a look at it. It could be an issue with the JS.